# Why won't my Redux change state change at all?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, redux, react-redux

In an attempt to see if Redux is working properly, inside `checkWinner()` I'm checking `console.log("win value (is redux working?) ==> " + win);` and the output is always:

```
win value (does redux work?) ==> [object Object]
```

The output should be `win value (does redux work?) ==> X`.  Is my Reducer written wrong?

Here's `Board.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Board.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actionTypes from '../../store/actions/actions';

class Board extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            winner: undefined,
        };

        this.gameState = {
            turn: 'X',
            gameLocked: false,
            gameEnded: false,
            board: Array(9).fill(''),
            totalMoves: 0
        }
    }

    clicked(box) {
        if(this.gameState.gameEnded || this.gameState.gameLocked) {
            return;
        }

        if(this.gameState.board[box.dataset.square] === '') {
            this.gameState.board[box.dataset.square] = this.gameState.turn;
            box.innerText = this.gameState.turn;

            this.gameState.turn = this.gameState.turn === 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';
            this.gameState.totalMoves++;
        }

        console.log("this.gameState.totalMoves ==> " + this.gameState.totalMoves);

        var result = this.checkWinner();

        // my attempt
        if(result === 'X') {
            this.gameState.gameEnded = true;
            let win = this.props.winnerValueRedux(this.state.winner);
            this.setState({
                winner: win,
                winnerLine: 'X wins'
            });
            console.log("win value (is redux working?) ==> " + win);
            console.log("X wins");
        // end of attempt

        } else if(result === 'O') {
            this.gameState.gameEnded = true;
            this.setState({
                winner: 'O',
                winnerLine: 'O wins'
            });
            console.log("O wins");
        } else if(result === "draw") {
            this.gameState.gameEnded = true;
            this.setState({
                winner: 'draw',
                winnerLine: 'match is a draw'
            });
        }
        console.log("result ==> " + result);

        if(this.gameState.turn === 'O' && !this.gameState.gameEnded) {
            this.gameState.gameLocked = true;

            setTimeout(() => {
                do {
                    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
                } while(this.gameState.board[random] !== '');
                this.gameState.gameLocked = false;
                console.log("reached here");
                this.clicked(document.querySelectorAll('.square')[random]);
            }, 3000)
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div id="game">
                <div id="state">{this.state.winnerLine}</div>
                <div id="head">
                    Tic Tac Toe
                </div>

                <div id="board" onClick={(e) => this.clicked(e.target)}>
                    <div className="square" data-square="0"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="1"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="2"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="3"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="4"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="5"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="6"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="7"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="8"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        winnerValue: state.winnerValue
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        winnerValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionTypes.WINNER_VALUE, value})
    };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Board);
```

Here's `winnerReducer.js`:

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actions';

const initialState = {
    winnerValue: undefined
};

const winnerReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log("[winnerReducer] => " + action.value);
    switch(action.type) {
        case actionTypes.WINNER_VALUE:
            return{
                ...state,
                winnerValue: action.value
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default winnerReducer;
```

Comment: Here in this line you are actually sending undefined value  let win = this.props.winnerValueRedux(this.state.winner); this.state.winner is undefined here

Comment: @Think-Twice yeah I tried switching it to `' '` but still got the same result.  I also tried switching `winnerValue` in `winnerReducer.js` but still got the same result.

Comment: please provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem :) [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú I don't quite understand what you mean by that :o.  This is all there is to it.

Comment: I really want to help, could you make a working project on CodeSandbox or publish it on GitHub :) so that I can support you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After invoking these codes:

```
let win = this.props.winnerValueRedux(this.state.winner);
console.log("win value (is redux working?) ==> " + win);
```

The result is:

```
win value (does redux work?) ==> [object Object]
```

After using `JSON.stringify()`, I figured out that the `[object Object]` is `{"type":"WINNER_VALUE"}` which is actually the **dispatched action**, we didn't see the `value` property present in this action, because its value was *undefined*.

And your question:

> The output should be win value (does redux work?) ==> X. Is my Reducer
>   written wrong?

Everything is fine, nothing's wrong. The wrong thing is about how we expected the value of `win` variable should be.

```
let win = this.props.winnerValueRedux(this.state.winner)
```

is equivalent to:

```
function winnerValueRedux(value){
   return dispatch({type: actionTypes.WINNER_VALUE, value})
}

let win = winnerValueRedux(value);
```

And, this is the key, the return value of the `dispatch(action)` method is the **dispatched action** which is an *object*. That's why you receive: `win value (does redux work?) ==> [object Object]`

For more information: [dispatch(action)](https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatch-action)

---

For now, we understand why we received that unexpected result.

The next part is checking whether our redux store worked or not.

I've checked it and it worked. This is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/6xlv5rvqqk

This is the codes that I used to dispatch actions to redux store:

```
if (result === "X") {
  this.gameState.gameEnded = true;
  this.props.winnerValueRedux("X");   //dispatch an action
} else if (result === "O") {
  this.gameState.gameEnded = true;
  this.props.winnerValueRedux("O");   //dispatch an action
} else if (result === "draw") {
  this.gameState.gameEnded = true;
  this.props.winnerValueRedux("draw");  //dispatch an action
}
```

This is the codes I used to get the redux state

```
<div id="state">{this.props.winnerValue}</div>   // get value from redux store
```

---

I've tried my best. Hopefully, that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Passing wrong or not updated (should be `winner`?) argument to `winnerValueRedux()` is a minor problem.

Main problem is not undertanding "redux flow":

Dispatcher doesn't return values, it emits messages/actions. Actions processed by reducers are updating state in store. Updated value 'returns' to component by `mapStateToProps`.

Search for some tutorial/examples.